# Function latest post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have next code for show latest post in wordpress. I want to add thumbnail and date. Any suggestion?

```
function last_article($atts){
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'posts' => 1,
   ), $atts));

   $return_string = '<ul>';
   query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'showposts' => $posts));
   if (have_posts()) : 
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
         $return_string .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
      endwhile;
   endif;
   $return_string .= '</ul>';

   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shortcode is pure evil. You should never ever use `extract()`. `extract()` is to be completely removed from Wordpress core. This should also tell you something how really bad `extract()` really is. See the corresponding [trac ticket here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22400)

Also, never ever use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

You should be using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

You should visit the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) in the codex and see how to properly construct a shortcode

With this all in mind, your code should look something like this

```
function last_article($atts){

   $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'posts' => 1,
    ), $atts );

   $return_string = '<ul>';
   $q = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'posts_per_page' => $a['posts']));
   if ($q->have_posts()) { 
      while ($q->have_posts()) { 
         $q->the_post();

         $return_string .= '<li>'.the_date().'</li>';
         $return_string .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
         if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
             $return_string .= '<li>'.the_post_thumbnail().'</li>';
         }
      }
   }
   $return_string .= '</ul>';

   wp_reset_postdata();
   return $return_string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how insert date and thumbnail in <li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    function last_article($atts){
       extract(shortcode_atts(array(
          'posts' => 1,
       ), $atts));

       $return_string = '<ul>';
       query_posts(array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'showposts' => $posts));
       if (have_posts()) : 
          while (have_posts()) : the_post();
             $return_string .= '<h4>'.the_date().'</h4>';
             $return_string .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
             if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
             $return_string .= '<div>'.the_post_thumbnail().'</div>';
             }
          endwhile;
       endif;
       $return_string .= '</ul>';

       wp_reset_query();
       return $return_string;
    }
```